# Index-assign value to single element in theano tensor variable

Tags: theano

Theano does not support index-assignment. Okay, but there is

```
theano.tensor.set_subtensor(x,y)
```

and it is [stated](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.set_subtensor) that

> If you want to do something like a[5] = b or a[5]+=b, see theano.tensor.set_subtensor() and theano.tensor.inc_subtensor() below.

So does set_subtensor simulate index-assignment operations? Well, not quite. set_subtensor, only seems to work as expected when ndims < 2, as is seen in the following example.

```
>>> a = theano.tensor.zeros(10)
>>> a.eval()
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> aa = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(a[5], 5.0)
>>> aa.eval()
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

cool, a.shape == aa.shape, can set a = aa to replicate a[5] = 5.0 Let's try it with more dims then.

```
>>> b = theano.tensor.zeros((5,5))
>>> b.eval()
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> bb = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(b[2][2], 5.0)
>>> bb.eval()
array([ 0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> bb.shape.eval()
array([5])
```

While set_subtensor did assign the specified value at the target index, it does not return the the entire updated tensor variable, but just the subtensor with the updated value.

Does anyone know how to get to index-assign values to single elements in theano tensors with ndims >= 2?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out. In order to index-assign values to single elements in a tensor with ndims >= 2, it seems you need to recursively set_subtensor the subtensor with the updated value up the dims. For example:

```
>>> b = theano.tensor.zeros((5,5))
>>> b.eval()
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> bb = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(b[2][2], 5.0)
>>> bb.eval()
array([ 0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> b = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(b[2], bb)
>>> b.eval()
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

With ndims=3

```
>>> c = theano.tensor.zeros((2,2,2))
>>> c.eval()
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)
>>> ccc = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(c[0][0][0], 5.0)
>>> ccc.eval()
array([ 5.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> cc = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(c[0][0], ccc)
>>> cc.eval()
array([[ 5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
>>> c = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(c[0], cc)
>>> c.eval()
array([[[ 5.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Maybe there is a simpler/quicker way to index-assign, but this is what I found.